# Is there any way to use "less" view python output in ipython

Tags: python, pipe, ipython

In *ipython* there is a magic `%less` which enables the regular shell `less` command. So we can use

```
less fname
```

or

```
%less fname
```

to see the content of *fname*. Even wonderful thing is that we can also use

```
cat fname | less
```

or

```
%cat fname | less
```

but **NOT(!!!)** `cat fname | %less` or `%cat fname | %less`.

in ipython as well!

Sadly I find that for the non-magic python functions, the output seems not able to be used together with pipe to less. For example, none of the below works.

```
print(os.environ.keys()) | %less
print(os.environ.keys()) | less
echo os.environ.keys() | %less
echo os.environ.keys() | less
os.environ.keys() | %less
os.environ.keys() | less
```

Is there way to resolve this?

---

Sorry I didn't search SO carefully since 2 similar questions are already answered.

**PLUS:** I would appreciate if someone tells the strange behaviours for the `%` and `non-%` magic version with the existence of "|".
I guess this is also answered, but it's hard for me to search with correct keywords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [21]: x = os.environ.keys()
In [22]: %page x
```

This was found by typing `%magic` and searching backward through the output for the string "page".

---

When a string like `%less`, `%page`, `%cat`, or `%ls` appears *at the beginning* of a command, it is treated as a magic function by IPython. Note that if you have `automagic` enabled, you do not need to type `%` explicitly for line magic; that is why `less` may behave the same as `%less` when typed at the beginning of a command.

When the magic function does not appear at the beginning of a command, the command is passed to Python and treated like regular Python code.

In Python `|` is the [bitwise-or operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

`%` calls the [`__mod__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mod).